# angularjs - object property is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my **Angular.js** app, I have one **parent controller**, which generate my present `longitude and latitude` so that I can get that data into my child controller. My code is given below:

**Parent Controller**

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
   angular.module('app').controller('InitCtrl', InitCtrl);
   function InitCtrl() {
      var init = this;
      init.g_map = {};
      init.g_map.current = {};
      let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      // current latitude & longitude
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        init.g_map.current.lat = position.coords.latitude;  
         init.g_map.current.lng = position.coords.longitude;
      });
   }
})();
```

**Child Controller**

```
(function() {
   'use strict';

   angular.module('app').controller('ListCtrl', ListCtrl);

   function ListCtrl($scope, $timeout, _, NgMap, RestaurantApi) {
      let list = this;

      list.load = function load() {
        let init = $scope.$parent.init;
        list.res = {};
        list.res = init.g_map.current;
        console.log("list.res  1: ", list.res);
        /* Output (console window):
             list.res 1 : >Object{}
                           {
                               lat: 'my-current-lat'
                               lng: 'my-current-lng'
                           }
            // here I have got my parent controller data
         */
        // but in the following console, I got undefine
        // even if I already got data which is printed previous console
        console.log("list.res  2 : ", list.res.lat, list.res.lng);
       /* Output (console window)
           list.res 2 : undefined undefined
        */
      }

     list.load();
   }

 })();
```

I don't understand why this is happening, any suggestion ?

Comment: `getCurrentPosition()` is **asynchronous**. Use promise or angular scope event so child can process data ***after*** it has been received. Or use a routing `resolve`

Comment: @charlietfl, I got your point, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm missing a comma after `lat: 'my-current-lat'` console output. Maybe there is a hidden bug?

You can try to access the properties using this syntax:

```
console.log('list.res 2: ', list.res['lat'], list.res['lng']);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function that gets the location is asynchronous, so you are trying to access its properties before it has them. Try the documentation of [promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

### Promises in an api call

I have a decent example of how the use a promise in this case, check this jsfiddle.net/0bghsjf8/ and let me know if you need anything else.